# Socket.io and heroku CORS problem after deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, cors, github-pages

I set up my `socket.io` server on `heroku` but I have problem with getting data from it to my app. I get cors error:

[image]

My app is hosted on gh-pages. Here is how my `socket.io` setup looks like:

```
const io = require("socket.io")(port, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://name.github.io/",
    methods: ["GET"],
  },
});
```

What should I put in origin, should it be `gh-pages` link or `heroku` app link? How can I fix that?

This is how my request looks like:

[image]

I tried putting `https://name.github.io/` or `https://name.herokuapp.com/`, to `origin` property but none of this worked

Answer (score -1):

For anyone having the same problem - I just removed `/` after url in `origin` and it worked :)

Answer (score -1):

You should pass `{ cors: true, origin: <your-client-url> }` as config option.